# В чем отличие использования vm от extend в Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extend

В чем преимущества экспорта функций и переменных через `extend` перед экспортом через переменную `vm`?

Через `vm`:

```
function MainCtrl () {
  var vm = this;

  function func1() {

  }

  vm.func1 = func1;
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

Через `extend`:

```
function MainCtrl () {

  function func1() {

  }

  var var1 = { smth: 'val' };
  function funcExt1() {
    func1();
  }

  angular.extend(this, {
    funcExt1: funcExt1,
    var1 : var1
  });
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.extend(this, {
   funcExt1: funcExt1,
   var1 : var1
});
```

расширяет(по факту, копирует свойства) "this" от объекта

```
{
   funcExt1: funcExt1,
   var1 : var1
}
```

В свою очередь конструкция this.var = 1 создает свойство var со значением 1

очень хорошо написано об extend в офф мануале

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend